# Casting a base class onto a derived class in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

Currently in my Java program, I have a base Parent class with several methods which return a new instance of itself. For example:

```
public BasePage fill(String input, By locator) {
    driver.findElement(locator).clear();
    driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(input);

    return new BasePage(driver);
}
```

As well, I have several classes which extend this base class with their own methods. My question is this: is there a way in my main program to call these Parent methods, but assign the returned value to a child class without using casts? For example, if I had a `loginPage` Child class which needed to use this method in a main program, how would I turn this:

```
loginPage = (LoginPage) loginPage.fill("username", usernameLocator);
```

into this:

```
loginPage = loginPage.fill("username", usernameLocator);
```

where I initialize the class:

```
public class LoginPage extends BasePage {
}
```

While not mentioned in this example, is it possible to allow it to return any of the child classes, such that it is not restricted to just one class.

Comment: Are you familiar with [`Java Polymorphism`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)?

Comment: I have read the page on Java Polymorphism, but it doesn't have any information on returning a parent class and assigning that value to a child class without casting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a way.  In the subclass (e.g. `LoginPage`), override the `fill` method.  With Java's [covariant return types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) (scroll to the bottom), you can specify `LoginPage` as the return type.

```
public LoginPage fill(String input, By locator) {
    driver.findElement(locator).clear();
    driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(input);

    return new LoginPage(driver);
}
```

That assumes that you can create a `LoginPage` with a `driver`, assumed to be of a `Driver` class, which means you need a subclass constructor that takes a `Driver`.

```
public LoginPage(Driver driver)
{
    super(driver);
    // Anything else LoginPage-specific goes here
}
```

Comment: The only problem here is that to get this each subclass would have to override a method by providing an exact copy of the superclass' implementation, except for the new Thing() bit.

Comment: I was hoping there was an approach that would allow me to return any of the children of the BasePage class. This does help with my situation though.

Answer (score 1):

There several ways to proceed here, but if the new instance if pretty much the same as the old one with perhaps some modifications I think you should consider to make your hierarchy clone-able.

```
public class BasePage implements Cloneable {

    public BasePage fill(String input, By locator) {
        driver.findElement(locator).clear();
        driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(input);

        return (BasePage) clone();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() {
      try {  
        return super.clone();
      } catch ( CloneNotSupportedException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("this can't ever happen!!!",ex);
      } 
    }
...
}
```

Then the child classes need to override the parent's fill with the appropriate cast

```
public class LoginPage extends BasePage {

    @Override
    public LoginPage fill(String input, By locator) {
        return (LoginPage) super.fill(input,locator);
    }
}
```

Notice that clone will always return an instance of the original invoking instance... in this case LoginPage.

This approach may not work or would need refinement depending on what are the other member fields in the hierarchy and how these are supposed to be shared between clones.

A different approach that works as long as you keep constant the signature of the constructor of all child classes, in this case (Driver), is to keep the logic of the method fill in the parent and select the appropriate child class by passing the class object...

```
public class BasePage {

  public <T extends BasePage> T fill(String input, By locator, Class<T> clazz) {
    driver.findElement(locator).clear();
    driver.findElement(locator).sendKeys(input);
    // not sure if the cast is even needed.
    try {
      return (T) clazz.getConstructor(Driver.class).newInstance(driver);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException("whoops! something went wrong",ex);
    } 
  }
}
```

Then to get a LoginPage...

```
 LoginPage lp = page.fill(input,loc,LoginPage.class);
```

You can overload fill in the children classes to avoid passing the class but then we would be doing as much as work as with the clone solution above.

Comment: Regarding your final section of code, it appears that the method `newInstance()` doesn't take any arguments. Should this be left blank and the constructor is inherited or do I need to import this method from a package to get the one that you used?

Comment: @bagelmakers sorry my bug as I was coding blind (without checking on APIs)... you have to get the appropriate constructor with getConstructor(Class ... x) and the call newInstance with the corresponding arguments. I have changed the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

No, not as such.  If `BasePage` is the formal type of the reference on which you invoke the given `fill()` method, then the formal type of the return value is `BasePage`.  You cannot treat that value as a subtype of `BasePage` without a cast.

In your particular example, even a cast should fail with a `ClassCastException` because the base class's method, which the subclass is not shown to override, returns an object whose class is `BasePage`, and such an object is not an instance of `LoginPage`.

However, a subclass could override that method, employing a covariant return type:

```
public class LoginPage extends BasePage {
    @Override
    public LoginPage fill(String input, Locator by) {
        return new LoginPage(/* ... */);
    }
}
```

In that case, if you invoke that method on a reference to a `LoginPage` (or one of *its* subclasses) then the return value is an instance of `LoginPage` and can be treated as such:

```
LoginPage page1 = new LoginPage();
LoginPage page2 = page1.fill("username", usernameLocator);
```